# Looking for clarification on struct pointers

Tags: c

So, I have structure:

```
typedef struct {
    int (*compare)(const void *a, const void *b);
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
} *QueueADT;
```

It's my understanding that calling it "*QueueADT" automatically makes any "QueueADT" item into a pointer. So:

```
QueueADT queue;
```

Would be a pointer to the structure previously defined. I'm wondering how you malloc such a structure. Normally it would just be:

```
QueueADT queue = malloc(sizeof(QueueADT));
```

But is "QueueADT" not a pointer? So aren't you only allocating enough memory for a pointer to the queue structure? I've been getting some invalid writes in valgrind with my code, which I'm thinking is a result of bad initialization of my queue.

Comment: I like to use the object proper in that situation: `QueueADT queue = malloc(sizeof *queue);`

Comment: It's a bad idea to hide a pointer behind a typedef, unless you use it as an opaque data type. Also, you might want to define a struct tag and a typedef for the tag using the same name.

Answer (score 4):

It's normal to define types for both the structure and pointers to it, like this:

```
typedef struct {
    ...
} QueueADT, *pQueueADT;
```

You can then use `sizeof(QueueADT)` as you suggest:

```
pQueueADT queue = malloc(sizeof(QueueADT));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm ecstatic to finally isolate and fix an issue that has been causing such problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
QueueADT queue = malloc(sizeof(*queue));
```

Comment: While this provides an answer, it is not yet a good answer because there is no explanation of why the OP should use this.  I recommend explaining why you've changed the code as shown.